# Check the status of copy

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to write a script to be called by Windows Task Scheduler every min. The script is supposed to look for a file in a network drive and move it somewhere else.

If a user copies a large file (something like 300 MB) to a Windows network drive, depending on the users locations and bandwidth it could take a couple of minutes for the file to get uploaded completely.

When the Task Scheduler calls my script, let's say it found a file, now I will create a temporary lock file so the next time the script is called it simply will exit because of that lock file, it knows the previous script that was called a min ago is active trying to move the file.

What is the best way for my PowerShell script to know when the file copy to the network drive completed and then start transferring the file somewhere else?

1. have some kind of while loop check the size of the file, pause    30 sec,  check the size again if equal, then I know the transfer is completed?
2. is there a PowerShell API to check to see if the file is in used or not? If not it means the upload completed?
3. any better more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I doubt you can see whether a file has open handles on a network share. After all, the file is open on a completely different computer. However, your first idea with watching the file size to stabilise seems good enough. Note that you shouldn't need a lock file or similar; you should be able to instruct Task Scheduler to only run the task if it's not currently running.

Comment: Why not use [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and configure the task to not start (again) if it's already running?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am more expert on Unix and not very familiar with Windows features. I didn't know that task scheduler has a feature to know if the previous task is still running. So how does robocopy works? will it know if the file still being uploaded and wait until it finishes or something I need to check for?

Comment: `robocopy` works more or less like `rsync`. If the file is locked it should output an error.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. Lets consider this scenario. User started to copy a 300 MB file to a  network driver under \\servername\shared\. a min passed and task scheduler  execute a powershell script. I'll check to see if file exist and if yes, then use robocopy to copy the file to same network drive but under different directory. Now does robocopy knows that the original file still being written to it and wait until the copy is finished before  cp it to the new location or will not copy and exit?

Comment: It will copy what's there (i.e. the partial content) and re-transmit the changed file on the next run. If you don't want that you probably need to create a [filesystemwatcher](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[powershell]+filesystemwatcher) to monitor the shared folder on the server.